# Objective-C / iOS: PopOver

Tags: ios, styles, uipopover

I´m using the UIPopOver in iOS, but mine looks like this:
[image]

but I want to make it look like this:

[image]

Please note that I DON´T want to use any 3rd-party-libary.

Maik

Comment: it is just a customised instance of the `UIPopoverController`, see the **[docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPopoverBackgroundView)** how you can customise via `UIPopoverBackgroundView` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`UIPopoverBackgroundView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPopoverBackgroundView) to modify the design of your popover view.